# How to concatenate feature maps?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I was trying to merge feature maps that I got from two different encoders which have different dimensions in Pytorch

simclr_features: `torch.Size([543, 512])`

imagenet_features: `torch.Size([543, 1024])`

so I wanted: `torch.Size([543, 1536])`. what is a possible solution to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`torch.cat`](https://torch.cat):

```
torch.cat((simclr_features, imagenet_features), dim=1)
```